# Set second axis to a plot, using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis

I want to perform a chart that involves two variables (weight - kg) and (rain - mm) through the years (1991 - 2021). BOTH VARIABLES ARE NOT RELATED!

Everything goes ok when plotting the graphs separated one from each other:

library(ggplot2)

```
    ggplot(data2, aes(x=ano_dtt)) +
      geom_col(aes(y=PesoAj220_d), fill="lightblue2") +
      ylim(0,300)
```

[image]

```
    ggplot(data2, aes(x=ano_dtt)) +
      geom_point(aes(y=ppt)) +
      geom_path(aes(y=ppt)) +
      ylim(0,1700)
```

[image]

But, when I try to add the second axis everything goes wrong!!!

```
    scaleRight <- 0.75
    
    ggplot(data2, aes(x=ano_dtt)) +
      geom_col(aes(y=PesoAj220_d), fill="lightblue2") +
      ylim(0,300) +
      geom_point(aes(y=ppt)) +
      geom_path(aes(y=ppt), colour="red", size=0.9) +
      ylim(0,1700)+
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scaleRight, name="precipitacion (mm)")) +
      labs(title = "", x="año", y="peso")
```

[image]

I also try this:

```
    scaleRight <- 0.75
    
    ggplot(data2, aes(x=ano_dtt)) +
      geom_col(aes(y=PesoAj220_d), fill="lightblue2") +
      ylim(0,300) +
      geom_point(aes(y=ppt)) +
      geom_path(aes(y=ppt), size=0.9) +
      ylim(c(0,1700))
```

[image]

But there is something wrong with the only axis present in the plot.

I think that the problem is with the

```
    scaleRight <- 0.75
```

Can someone help to solve this problem? I'm pretty sure that is very very easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you face is that you have to scale your secondary y-axis values to fall within the range of the primary x-axis. As you guessed, multiplying the secondary y-axis values by a set value (scaleRight) is not how to achieve your goal.

I struggle with scaling within a `sec_axis()` function, so I prefer to scale the secondary y-axis values prior to plotting. The approach outlined below creates the same number of axis breaks on both y-axes, comment if you prefer a different number of breaks each side and I'll update the code.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
set.seed(1)
data2 <- data.frame(ano_dtt = 1991:2021,                   
                    PesoAj220_d = sample(250:300, 31),
                    ppt = sample(750:1550, 31))

# Set y-axes limits, must exceed or equal min/max data values
# Set min and max limits for primary (left) y-axis
l.y.min <- 0
l.y.max <- 300

# Set min and max limits for secondary (right) y-axis
r.y.min <- 0
r.y.max <- 1700

# Function to scale secondary y-axis values
axis_scaled <- function(x, y, z, max.var) {
  y <- ifelse(is.na(x), NA, ((x - y) / (z - y)) * max.var)
  y <- y[2:(length(y)-1)]
}

# Add scaled secondary y-axis values to data2
data2$scaled_ppt <- axis_scaled(c(r.y.min, data2$ppt, r.y.max),
                                r.y.min, r.y.max, l.y.max)

# Create breaks for primary y-axis and labels for secondary y-axis
l.y.breaks <- seq(l.y.min, l.y.max, length.out = 5)
r.y.labels <- seq(r.y.min, r.y.max, length.out = length(l.y.breaks))

# Plot
ggplot(data2, aes(x = ano_dtt)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = PesoAj220_d), fill = "lightblue2") +
  geom_point(aes(y = scaled_ppt)) +
  geom_path(aes(y = scaled_ppt), colour = "red", linewidth = 0.9) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1991:2021) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = l.y.breaks,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .,
                                         breaks = l.y.breaks,
                                         labels = r.y.labels,
                                         name = "precipitacion (mm)")) +
  labs(title = "", x = "año", y = "peso") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, that it is exactly what I needed =). Unfortunatelly, the script didnt work good enough for me :'( I'll keep trying.

Comment: @MariaVictoriaTopayan - if you update your question and include further details about what isn't working, and how you want your final output to look, I'm happy to help you troubleshoot. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful information about how to share example data. I'm guessing it's something to do with the min and max values of your actual data?

Comment: The code worked perfectly. The issue was in the underlying data structure. That is, I had data for a period of 31 years but there were several records for each year for the weight variable (peso), so what I was looking to plot (and I didn't mentioned) was the average of such records for each year. In addition there was only one rain record for each year. the solution was easy: I used a df that contains the directly the averaged weight for each year and its ppt record.